# Corrupted image is being saved with PIL

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am having an issue whereby manipulating image pixels is causing a corrupted image to be saved...

So, I open an image using PIL, and then convert it to a NumPy array:

```
image = Image.open("myimage.png")
np_image = np.asarray(image)
```

Then, I transpose the image, to convert it from `[x][y][channel]` to `[channel][x][y]`:

```
pixels = np.transpose(np_image, (2, 0, 1))
```

If I then transpose this image back to `[x][y][channel]`, create a PIL image from this array, and then save the image:

```
image1 = np.transpose(pixels, (1, 2, 0))
image2 = Image.fromarray(image1, 'RGB')
image2.save('image2.png')
```

Then the image saved is identical to "myimage.png".

However, if instead of the above code, I first assign `pixels` to an element in an array of images:

```
images = np.zeros([10, 3, 50, 50]) # The images are 50x50 with 3 channels
images[0] = pixels
image3 = np.transpose(images[0], (1, 2, 0))
image4 = Image.fromarray(image3, 'RGB')
image4.save('image4.png')
```

Then "image4.png" is corrupted. It appears as follows:

[image]

Whereas "myimage.png" is actually:

[image]

So why is it that if I save the image when I directly transpose `pixels`, the image saved is as expected, but when I set `pixels` to the first element in the array `images`, and then transpose this image, the saved image is corrupted?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, there was a small mistake: I've now changed it from `np.array([10, 3, 50, 50])` to  `np.zeros([10, 3, 50, 50])`. But the problem I was having is still the same...

Answer (score 4):

The default data type created by `numpy.zeros` is floating point, so

```
images = np.zeros([10, 3, 50, 50])
```

creates a floating point array.  Then in the assignment

```
images[0] = pixels
```

the values in `pixels` are cast to floating point in order to store them in `images`, so `image3` is a floating point array.  This affects the values that are stored in the PNG file when the corresponding image is saved.  I don't know the rules that PIL/Pillow follow when given a floating point array, but apparently it is not the desired behavior here.

To fix this, create `images` using the same data type as `np_image` (most likely this is `numpy.uint8`):

```
images = np.zeros([10, 3, 50, 50], dtype=np_image.dtype)
```