# PIL: Imageobject.save() after drawing completely corrupts images and smurfs the ouput

Tags: image, tkinter, draw, python-imaging-library

I have these two functions in my program:

```
def depict_ph_increase(x,y,color, imobject):
    program_print(color)
    draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(imobject)
    draw.text((x, y),color,(255,255,255))
    imobject.save('tmp-out.gif')
    im_temp = PIL.Image.open("tmp-out.gif")#.convert2byte()
    im_temp = im_temp.resize((930, 340), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    MAP_temp = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_temp)
    map_display_temp = Label(main, image=MAP_temp)
    map_display_temp.image = MAP_temp # keep a reference!
    map_display_temp.grid(row=4,column=2, columnspan=3)

def read_temp_pixels(temperature_file, rngup, rngdown):
    temp_image_object = PIL.Image.open(temperature_file)
    (length, width) = get_image_size(temp_image_object)
    (rngxleft, rngxright) = rngup
    (rngyup,rngydown) = rngdown
    print 'the length and width is'
    print length, width
    hotspots = 5;
    for hotspot in range(0,hotspots):
        color = "#ffffff"
        while color == "#ffffff" or color == "#000000" or color == "#505050" or color == "#969696":
            yc = random.randint(rngxleft, rngxright)
            xc = random.randint(rngyup,rngydown)
            color = convert_RGB_HEX(get_pixel_color(temp_image_object, xc, yc))
        depict_ph_increase(xc,yc,color, temp_image_object)
```

The bottom one calls the top one. Their job is to read in this image: [image]

It then randomly selects a few pixels, grabs their colors, and writes the hex values of the colors on top. But, when it redisplays the image, it gives me this garbage:
[image]

Those white numbers up near the upper right corner are the hex values its drawing. Its somehow reading the values from the corrupted image, despite the fact that I don't collect the values until AFTER I actually call the `ImageDraw()` method. Can someone explain to me why it is corrupting the image?

Some background--the `get_pixel_color()` function is used several other times in the program and is highly accurate, its just reading the pixel data from the newly corrupted image somehow. Furthermore, I do similar image reading (but not writing) at other points in my code.

If there is anything I can clarify, or any other part of my code you want to see, please let me know. You can also view the program in its entirety at my github here: https://github.com/jrfarah/coral/blob/master/src/realtime.py It should be commit #29.

Other SO questions I have examined, to no avail: [Corrupted image is being saved with PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094568/corrupted-image-is-being-saved-with-pil)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by editing this line:

```
temp_image_object = PIL.Image.open(temperature_file)
```

to be

```
temp_image_object = PIL.Image.open(temperature_file).convert('RGB')
```